# Consultar campo numérico duplicado no sql server

Tags: sql-server, query, select

Bom dia!

Tenho uma tabela de notas e no mês de dezembro houve uma duplicidade de várias notas. Essas notas duplicadas tem número diferentes, entretanto, o valor total da nota é exatamente igual.

Já tentei usar o having count e não obtive sucesso na pesquisa.

Como posso identificar essas notas com números diferentes e valores iguais? O campo do valor total que é o duplicado é numérico.

Abaixo tem o exemplo de uma das notas que estão duplicadas.

select  numpdv,
numnota,
valortotal,
dataemissao,
id_nfe
from tab_nota_header where dataemissao between '2020-12-04 00:00:00' and '2020-12-04 23:59:59'
and codloja=3
and numpdv=21
and valortotal=14.00

O resultado da pesquisa
[image: Resultado do select]

Fazendo esse select eu consigo identificar quais valores estão repetindo.

select  valortotal,
count(valortotal)
from tab_nota_header where dataemissao between '2020-12-04 00:00:00' and '2020-12-04 23:59:59'
and codloja=3
and numpdv=21
group by valortotal
having count(valortotal) > 1

Ele me retorna esse resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que preciso do número da nota e o número do pdv e quando acrescento esses campos na consulta, ele não trás o resultado que preciso.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

Segue uma sugestão para testes utilizando a função *Count* com as claúsulas *Over* e *Partition By* para obter a quantidade de linhas com o mesmo valor nas colunas valortotal, numpdv e dataemissao:

```
with CTE_Count as
(
  select 
    numpdv, 
    numnota, 
    valortotal, 
    dataemissao, 
    id_nfe,
    count(*) over(partition by valortotal, numpdv, dataemissao) as QtdMesmoValor
  from tab_nota_header 
  where 
    dataemissao between '2020-12-04 00:00:00' and '2020-12-04 23:59:59' and 
    codloja = 3 and 
    numpdv = 21
)

select * from CTE_Count
where QtdMesmoValor > 1
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Boa tarde!

Imex, você não me ajudou, na verdade você me salvou.

Deu certo a query e agora vou conseguir dar sequência na correção que preciso.

Podemos encerrar. Mais uma vez, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde!

Imex, você não me ajudou, na verdade você me salvou.

Deu certo a query e agora vou conseguir dar sequência na correção que preciso.

Podemos encerrar. Mais uma vez, muito obrigado!